# Example of field $K$ with $\mathrm{char}(K) > 0 $, such that $[K(\alpha):K] = [K(\beta):K]$ but $K(\alpha) \not \cong K(\beta)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I'd like to fine an example of field $K$ and elements $\alpha, \beta$ such that $\mathrm{char}(K) = p> 0 $, $[K(\alpha):K] = [K(\beta):K]$ but $K(\alpha) \not \cong K(\beta)$.

This obviously can't work if $K$ is a finite field. So I need to find a non-finite $K$. The only ones that pop into my head are $\mathbb F_p(t)$, $\mathbb F_p(t^p)$ and $\overline{\mathbb F}_p$ for $t$ an indererminate, but I'm struggling to find an example.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ will work. Try quadratic extensions.

Comment: Skillfully pick two irreducible quadratic polynomials in $F_3(t)[X]$ such that the corresponding quotients are not isomorphic.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Would something simple like $K = \mathbb F_p(t)$, $\alpha = \sqrt{2}, \beta = i$ work?

Comment: Or would that only work in the case where $-1$ isn't a quadratic residue mod $p$?

Comment: @Jonathan: if $p$ is such that both of those are quadratic extensions, then both of those extensions are just $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}(t)$. You need to use $t$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I guess my problem is that I'm struggling to see what will stop the resulting extensions from being isomorphic.

Comment: @Jonathan: do you know how to show that two quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ aren't isomorphic?

Comment: If $L_1 = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{a})$ and $L_2 = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{b})$ are two quadratic extensions with $a,b \in \mathbb Q$, then if $b$ has no square root in $L_1$ then the two aren't isomorphic (and likewise for $a$)

Comment: @Jonathan: yep. That's still true here.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So taking something like $\alpha = \sqrt{t}$, $\beta = \sqrt{t^3}$ would work? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jonathan: no, those are isomorphic (since $\alpha = t \beta$). Use $t$ in one of the extensions but not the other!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I think that's the worst mistake I've made since I first learned what a field is. I now understand what's going on, and withdraw sheepishly. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Let us try to save this question from the Well of Oblivion of Unanswered Questions, following the solution already detailed in the comments of Qiaochu and the OP Jonathan:

Take $$K:=\mathbb F_3(t)\,,\,\alpha:=\sqrt{t}\,,\,\beta=\sqrt{-1}$$

As $\,\alpha\,,\,\beta\notin K\,\,\,\text{but}\,\,\alpha^2\,,\,\beta^2\in K\,$ , the extensions $\,K(\alpha)\,,\,K(\beta)\,$ are both quadratic ones , so $\,[K:K(\alpha)]=[K:K(\beta)]=2\,$, yet these two fields cannot be isomorphic as, say $\,\beta\notin K(\alpha)\,$ (and also the other way around)